# Speeding up or alternatives to group by and lag in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-transform

I notice this operation is very time consuming for seemingly simple calculation. It probably explains more than 60% out of all duration to complete the current R script.

The actual data contains about `500,000 rows` with about `100,000 unique ids` (column for group by).

And the type of column used for calculating the `lag difference` is of `lubridate::dmy_hms`. Therefore the lag difference is looking at `seconds` time difference.

I think these may play a role in why it takes so long to compute but I'm also curious whether I can rewrite the following code differently or maybe just use `R base` if it's way faster (maybe at the expense of doing some data type gymnastic to ensure other `dplyr`-like operations remain intact)

```
dief <- tibble(id = rep(letters,4), time = 1:length(id) + sample(1:30, length(id),replace = T))
dief %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(time_difference = (time - lag(time)))
```

Comment: Have you tried with `data.table` ? `setDT(dief)[, time_difference := time - shift(time), id]`

Comment: @RonakShah I'm not proficient with data.table but I'm open to that solution

Comment: @RonakShah I just found about this `dtplyr` package, maybe it's possible to maintain the same `dplyr` readable syntax while leveraging on `data.table` speed?

Comment: time_diff = `diff(time)`?

Comment: @Eyayaw I think diff(time) is different that lag(time) though.

Comment: `diff(x) == x-lag(x) `

Comment: @Eyayaw Sorry my bad! Should have checked the function first, I thought it was a subset  `diff` for some reasons. I'll compare `diff` against the `tidytable` solution below. Probably can combine both too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options are dtplyr and [tidytable](https://markfairbanks.github.io/tidytable/reference/index.html). Personally I'm using the latter.
Both leverage on data.table but uses dplyr-style code.

```
dief <- tibble(id = rep(letters,4), time = 1:length(id) + sample(1:30, length(id),replace = T))
dief %>%
  arrange.(id) %>%
  mutate.(time_difference = (time - lags.(time)),
          .by = id)
```

Here are some [speed comparisons](https://markfairbanks.github.io/tidytable/articles/speed_comparisons.html).

Comment: Game changer! Thanks for introducing this new library. I think I have to wait until I can accept this answer.

Comment: I tried using `diff` from R base instead of lag, is there any restriction to functions used within `mutate.`. Here's the updated code `dief %>%
  arrange.(id) %>%
  mutate.(time_difference = diff(time),
          .by = id)`

Comment: amazing this was so much faster

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remain within dplyr, the following is an implementation of lag() that avoids grouping the tibble. The running time scales much better with many groups.

```r
lag_grouped_by = function(var, ...){
 # ... vars to group_by
  args <- list(...)
       
  tibble(!!!args, .name_repair = ~paste0("var", 1:length(args))) %>%
        mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
        mutate(var = var) %>% 
        arrange(across(-c(var,row))) %>%
        mutate(across(-c(var,row), ~replace_na(.x,"encode_NAs"))) %>%
        mutate(across(-c(var,row), ~.x==lag(.x))) %>% 
        mutate(cond = rowSums(across(-c(var,row))) == length(args)) %>% 
        mutate(lag_var = lag(var)) %>%
        arrange(row) %>%
        mutate(lag_var = if_else(cond, lag_var, NA, NA)) %>%
        pull(lag_var)
    }
```

Now, simply run the following:

```r
dief %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  mutate(
       lag_time = lag_grouped_by(time, id),
       time_difference = (time - lag_time)
      )
```